# what is VLAN aware switching , and how is it different from Tagging?

Tags: networking

Can anyone Please help me answer , what VLAN aware and VLAN unaware switching is ? And how is it different from the concept of Tagging and Untagging. I browsed a lot on VLAN aware switching but couldn't find anything of much help.I excatly know what tagging and untagging is. Tagging is a method used to differentiate IP packets of different VLAN's . But I don't know ,what VLAN aware switching is. 
It would be really helpful if someone can help me out understand the above mentioned doubt.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: we need some context. A "VLAN-Aware" switch might be a L3Switch/(b)router cabable of being both a switch and a router, and thus capable of routing between VLANs, or it may just mean that the switch is capable of 802.1q. The term "VLAN-Aware" is not a technical term with a precise meaning, so without additional context, we could not tell you for sure. I would certainly say that a switch that did not support VLANs would be "VLAN-Unaware", but as to whether VLAN-Aware indicates that the switch can perform tagging, or means something more, we cannot tell.

Comment: My question is in context with L3 switch

Comment: Ok. so usually you need a router to route between VLANs. with a L3 switch, the router components are built into the device, so you don't need any external router, and your trunking will likely be easier to configure. Does that answer your question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch that can recognize tagged and untagged frames is a VLAN-Aware switch.

Otherwise, if the switch is unable to recognize tagged frames then it is a VLAN-unaware switch.

Comment: So, you mean that not all the switches can identify tagged IP packets, and only VLAN aware switches can identify and segregate tagged packet traffic?sorry for silly question, I'm just started learning networking.

Comment: @novice, that is correct, only a switch that supports 802.1Q is capable of processing frame tags.

Comment: Can a switch function as both VLAN aware switching and VLAN unaware switching ,based on the requirements? Or Do we have seperate switches meant for both of the above functions?

Comment: switching is switching. VLANs are not so much a property of the traffic but a property of the pathway itself (though 802.1q has a header for trunking), so for instance, when a port receives a broadcast frame incoming, it will only send that broadcast out on ports that are in the same VLAN(s) the receiving port belongs to. As such a port can be configured to be in any given VLAN or none at all. A VLAN does represent a barrier at layer2 however, so you will have to configure your IP ranges/trunking/routing/firewalling/etc to work correctly with whatever virtual topology you create.